# Failed Installation of Visual Studio 2013 Pro on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10, failed-installation

On a new installed Windows 10 Pro. I installed Visual Studio 2013 Pro and the error message, Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 (KB2829760) Package failed, is shown after the installation. The screenshot

[image: http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B841rccm7zZWRkxoU2pWX0FyV1FrTW1naEdWUU9FbmtCMkhr/view?usp=sharing]

Then I repaired it but with the same error message. The log file

http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B841rccm7zZWaVludENGeVFxWXNXREJIWXE5NFZoMnhLVFBj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: download the VS2013 ISo which already includes the Update 5 and try again

Comment: Your log file indicates that the system fails to execute `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\07D2D6FD53E7EDE1FB612619A11BBCD5530A3E56\packages\vsupdate_kb2829760\vsupdate_kb2829760.exe`. Try verifying that the file is not corrupted